# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regex pattern near index

Tags: java, android, regex

While splitting to below code

```
String s = "12+12";
String[] sr = s.split("+");
```

I am getting this error in logcat

```
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029): +
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):  ^
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:407)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:390)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1832)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1813)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at net.telivo.fiestacancun.ui.calllog.CallLogDetailsFragment$1.onClick(CallLogDetailsFragment.java:171)
    09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-03 15:57:22.489: E/AndroidRuntime(22029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a **regex**.

If you don't want to escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `+`, you can use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a **literal pattern String** for the specified String.

---

```
String sr[] = s.split(Pattern.quote("+"));
```

`+` will be now treated as a regular character and not a metacharacter.

Answer (score 11):

You should escape the `+` character.

```
String s = "12+12";
String[] sr = s.split("\\+");
```

Escaping a regex is usually done by `\`, but in Java `\` is represented as `\\`.

Answer (score 5):

`+` should be escaped, cause `+` is used to represent one of the [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

it should be `s.split("\\+");`

Answer (score 2):

Since `+`  is a meta character and have a special meaning in `regex` You have to escape that meta  character

```
String s = "12+12";
String[] sr = s.split("\\+");
```

[oracle docs on the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)